# How to do kriging on a country map from a linear model

Tags: raster, r, polygon, interpolation, kriging

I would like to use ordinary kriging to interpolate model predictions on a grid. In my code underneath, GPS is a 'SpatialPointsDataFrame' and EU is a 'SpatialPolygonDataFrame'. All covariates for estimating the model are contained in 'All_data'.

```
# Merge points with data 
GPS = merge(GPS, All_data, by.x = "nuts", by.y = "geo")
GPS <- GPS[!is.na(GPS@data$Value),]
proj4string(GPS) = CRS("+init=epsg:28992")

# Merge polygons with data 
EU = merge(EU, All_data, by.x = "nuts", by.y = "geo")
EU = subset(EU, EU@data$nuts %in% GPS@data$nuts)
proj4string(EU) = proj4string(GPS)

# Create a grid     
ext <- extent(EU)
r <- raster(ext, res=0.1)  
r <- rasterize(EU, r, field=1)
EU_grid = as(r, 'SpatialPixels')

# Estimate linear model
OLS_model = lm(Value ~ pop + unemp, data = GPS_coords) 

EU_grid$lm_pred <- predict(OLS_model, newdata = EU_grid)
```

However, I keep getting the error

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'pop' not found
```

Does anyone know how to do ordinary kriging from a lm-object?

Comment: What you are trying to do with this code is not kriging but predicting with your model. `pop not found` means what it means, i.e. you do not have any column named `pop` in your newdata `EU_grid`. If you want to be able to predict on a new area, you need to have a raster with `pop` and `unemp` information layers. By the way, you can use `predict` directly on a `raster` object.